# How to upload multiple files using Multer and Express to MongoDB in a EDIT request?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file-upload, multer

Now I need to upload documents with field names wForm and article.

I tried so many but couldn't figure out this. It would be very helpful if someone can find what's wrong with the code.

1. SkillSource is a scheme modal.
2. JOI library is used for validation of inputs.
3. Multer is used to upload multiple files

This is the file consisting middleware

```
const skillSourceSchema = Joi.object({
  cname: Joi.string().min(3).max(50).required(),
});
    
const upload = multer({
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1000000000,
  },
  fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|png|pdf)$/)) {
      cb(new Error("Only upload files with jpg or jpeg or png or pdf format."));
    } else {
      console.log("uploading");
    }
    cb(undefined, true); 
  },
}).fields([{name: "wForm", maxCount: 1,},{ name: "article",maxCount: 1,}]);

router.post("/skill-source/:id", upload, async (req, res) => {
  const skillSource = await SkillSource.findById(req.params.id).exec();

  const user = {
    username: skillSource.username,
    cname: req.body.cname,
    wForm: req.files.wForm[0].buffer,
    article: req.files.article[0].buffer,
  };

  try {
    const { error } = await skillSourceSchema.validateAsync(req.body);
    if (error) {
      res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
      return;
    } else {
      skillSource.set(user);
      await skillSource.save();
      res.send("Skill Source Edited Successfully");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: you are forgot to add what is the problem in your code?